# Manipulating an array is reflected in all variables referring to it

Tags: ruby, mutable

If I do this

```
x = y = z = 1
z = 20
```

then I get

```
"#{x}----#{y}----#{z}"
# => "1----1----20"
```

Now, if I do something like this:

```
a = b = c = []
```

then I get this:

```
"#{a}-----#{b}-----#{c}"
# => "[]-----[]-----[]"
```

But if I do the following:

```
c[0] = 'a'
c[1] = 'b'
c[2] = 'c'
```

I get this:

```
"#{a}-----#{b}-----#{c}"
# => "[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]-----[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]-----[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"
```

In case of `x`, `y`, `z`, when I assigned `z` to `20`, then `x` and `y` retained the value `1`. For `Arrays`, even though I assigned value to `c[]` only, the change was reflected in `a`,`b`. What is happening with the `Array`s?

Answer (score 1):

With `z = 20`, you are change `z` to reference another object,

With `c[0] = 'a'` , you are changing the original object which `a` and `b` is also referencing to.

Answer (score 1):

Think of what objects are being assigned to what variables, after all a variable is simply a handle for an object. In ruby everything is an object, and variables are just how you interact with them.

So...

```
a = b = 1
```

This sets `a` and `b` to reference the same object.  If I later say:

```
a = 2
```

Then I have set `a` to reference a new object, which shouldn't affect `b` at all, which is happily still `1`. The interpeter takes one simple step.

1. set local variable `a` to the object `2`.

But, following that logic:

```
a = b = []
```

Again, `a` and `b` reference the same object. An array this time.  But now when we do this:

```
a[0] = 'hello'
```

We have a different scenario here. You aren't changing what object `a` references at all. You are finding the object `a` references and then modifying that object.

Think about what the interpreter will do. It will take the following steps when executing that line.

1. Find the object referenced by `a` (which happens to be the same object referenced by `b`)
2. Set the value at the `0` index of that object to the string `"hello"`

All this is to say that simple local variable assignment like:

```
a = 1
```

Is a somewhat different operation when there is a layer of indirection present like these:

```
a[0] = 'hello'
a.foo = 'bar'
a.set_value 'some val'
```

---

Or think of setting a value in an array like calling a method on that array. So the difference becomes easier to grasp if you think of `a[0] = 'foo'` as:

```
a.set_value(0, 'foo')
```

Something like this is actually what happens in ruby arrays. Turns out assigning a value to an array index calls the `[]=(index, value)` method. These are all valid and equivalent.

```
a[0] = 'foo'
a.[]=(0, 'foo')
a.send('[]=', 0, 'foo')
```

I point this out only because when expressed as an invocation of a method it becomes very clear we are modifying an existing object here.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby you have methods which change it's object and methods which return new objects (the documentation of the method will mention this). Integers can not mutate: two will always be two. Playing around with the object_id may clear things up:

```
puts 1.object_id # 3
a = 1
puts a.object_id # 3
puts 20.object_id # 41
a = 20
puts a.object_id # 41

b = []
puts b.object_id # a number
b[1]=1 # mutating object
puts b.object_id # same number
b = b+[2] # the + method results in new object http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-2B
puts b.object_id # another number
```